# Explain using mine.get inside a salt-state

Tags: salt-stack

Can someone give me an idiots explanation of how the following works:

```
{% for server, addrs in salt['mine.get']('roles:web', 'network.ip_addrs', expr_form='grain') | dictsort() %}
server {{ server }} {{ addrs[0] }}:80 check
{% endfor %}
```

The pillar file looks like:

```
mine_functions:
  network.ip_addrs: [eth0]
```

What does salt assign to the first two values, `server` and `addrs`?
How would you use multiple mine options in the above? i.e. if your pillar file had an extra mine function like so:

```
mine_functions:
     network.ip_addrs: [eth0]
      role:
        - mine_function: grains.get
        - role
```

How could you then access the role function in the first code snippet?

Hopefully this makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Mine

The mine functions, defined in your pillar, tells the minions to push some information about them to the salt master. Then you can access it from any minion, using `mine.get`. This is documented in [this page](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/).

### mine.get

First, you can get a look at the `mine.get` result yourself:

```
salt 'minion0' mine.get 'roles:web' 'network.ip_addrs' expr_form='grain'
minion0:
    ----------
    minion1:
        - ip1
        - ip2
    minion2:
        - ip
```

So you got a dict, with keys being the minions ids, and values lists of network ip addresses. The `dictsort()` function sorts the keys before being passed to the variables of the loop.

You end up with `server` containing the minion id, and `addrs` a list of its ip addresses.

The first argument filters which minions data you want to get, with the third one (`expr_form`) being the filter type of this filter. You can use `glob`, `grain`, `compound`, basically any [salt targeting](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/index.html).

Now, to access the `role` mined data, you would just replace `network.ip_addrs` with `role`.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very helpful explanation.